# How can I use Get-ChildItem to get a list of files that the repository reports as modified?

Tags: powershell, mercurial

So the following will let me do something on a list of files:

```
$stuff = Get-ChildItem .\* -recurse -include ('*.txt', '*.doc')
foreach ($s in $stuff){
    Write-Host $s
}
```

However, I would like `$stuff` to be the results of my repo telling me which files have changed

> hg stat -m *.txt *.doc

But this command returns something like:

```
M foo.txt
M bar.doc
```

When what I really need is:

```
.\foo.txt
.\bar.doc
```

Comment: Why not parse the output of `hg`?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to parse the output of `hg`.  AFAIK, there is not native functionality.  The following code will catch your changes:

```
# |?{$_} ignores empty splits
$changes = (hg stat -m *.txt *.doc) -split 'M\s' | Where-Object { $_ }

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include @('*.txt','*.doc') |
    Where-Object { $changes -contains $_.Name }
```